# How to create a dotted border around a box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, border, flutter-layout, dotted-line

I am building a list of boxes layouts in my app using flutter. I want dotted border around the box. I have used `card` widget to create the boxes. But, how can I get dotted border around the boxes?

Comment: Have a look at the solution in this [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4858#issuecomment-472716207). Also the issue is about the missing of a solution for a circular border.

Comment: Flutter release plugin for dotted border, show full example https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252124/11827756

Answer (score 85):

### EDIT

I have added this as a package in [pub](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border).

Now, all you need to do is

```
DottedBorder(
  color: Colors.black,
  gap: 3,
  strokeWidth: 1,
  child: FlutterLogo(size: 148),
)
```

### Working Solution [Outdated]

[image: Dashed Border Image]

Like [tomerpacific](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10632369) said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374249/6891637), Flutter does not have a default implementation for dashed border at the moment.

I worked for some time yesterday and was able to come up with a solution using `CustomPainter`. Hope this helps someone.

Add the `DashedRect` to your container, like so

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          width: 300,
          color: Colors.black12,
          child: DashedRect(color: Colors.red, strokeWidth: 2.0, gap: 3.0,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### DashedRect.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class DashedRect extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double gap;

  DashedRect(
      {this.color = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 1.0, this.gap = 5.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(strokeWidth / 2),
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter:
              DashRectPainter(color: color, strokeWidth: strokeWidth, gap: gap),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DashRectPainter extends CustomPainter {
  double strokeWidth;
  Color color;
  double gap;

  DashRectPainter(
      {this.strokeWidth = 5.0, this.color = Colors.red, this.gap = 5.0});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint dashedPaint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    double x = size.width;
    double y = size.height;

    Path _topPath = getDashedPath(
      a: math.Point(0, 0),
      b: math.Point(x, 0),
      gap: gap,
    );

    Path _rightPath = getDashedPath(
      a: math.Point(x, 0),
      b: math.Point(x, y),
      gap: gap,
    );

    Path _bottomPath = getDashedPath(
      a: math.Point(0, y),
      b: math.Point(x, y),
      gap: gap,
    );

    Path _leftPath = getDashedPath(
      a: math.Point(0, 0),
      b: math.Point(0.001, y),
      gap: gap,
    );

    canvas.drawPath(_topPath, dashedPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(_rightPath, dashedPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(_bottomPath, dashedPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(_leftPath, dashedPaint);
  }

  Path getDashedPath({
    required math.Point<double> a,
    required math.Point<double> b,
    required gap,
  }) {
    Size size = Size(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y);
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
    bool shouldDraw = true;
    math.Point currentPoint = math.Point(a.x, a.y);

    num radians = math.atan(size.height / size.width);

    num dx = math.cos(radians) * gap < 0
        ? math.cos(radians) * gap * -1
        : math.cos(radians) * gap;

    num dy = math.sin(radians) * gap < 0
        ? math.sin(radians) * gap * -1
        : math.sin(radians) * gap;

    while (currentPoint.x <= b.x && currentPoint.y <= b.y) {
      shouldDraw
          ? path.lineTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)
          : path.moveTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
      shouldDraw = !shouldDraw;
      currentPoint = math.Point(
        currentPoint.x + dx,
        currentPoint.y + dy,
      );
    }
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I do not expect this to fit in with all use cases and there is a lot of room for customization and improvement. Comment if you find any bugs.

Comment: How can you add a border only on the right side or left side?

Comment: i'd like to add that the flutter team decided against implementing dashed lines (and i think this includes dashed borders as well), because of performance. See this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4858

Comment: @Jens And not provide/ try to implement internal alternative. In other words, "lol"

Comment: Can we flag this as the answer? Because I also thought about CustomPaint here for the only solution.

Comment: Thank you !!! you have saved my day :) but can you please share code for circular radius instead of just Rectangle?

Comment: @ShreeSoftech you could just wrap the widget in a ClipRRect

Answer (score 17):

You can use [dotted_border](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border) Flutter package

```
return DottedBorder(
   borderType: BorderType.RRect,
   radius: Radius.circular(20),
   dashPattern: [10, 10],
   color: Colors.grey,
   strokeWidth: 2,
   child: Card(
       color: Colors.amber,
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
       ),
       child: Center(child: Text("hi")),
   )
```

[image: dotted_border around card]

Answer (score 6):

There is an one plugin for draw dotted border around widgets

https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border

Using this plugin you can draw dotted or dashed border

```
//1. Install the plugin by add dependencies in pubspace.yaml
dotted_border: ^1.0.6
```

Add below code for show border

```
DottedBorder(
color: Colors.black,
strokeWidth: 1,
child: FlutterLogo(size: 148),
)
```

Comment: Just pointing out that I am the author of this package and the package is not endorsed/affiliated by Flutter in any way.

Comment: @Ajil O  Oh sorry for that, very good plugin , good work

Answer (score 3):

```
CustomPaint(
      painter: DottedBorderPainter(),
      child:Container(
            child: Text('dashed border',style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 13.5,color: Colors.black))))




class DottedBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        final paint = Paint()
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..strokeWidth = 2
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    
        final double dashWidth = 5; // Width of each dash
        final double dashSpace = 5; // Space between each dash
    
        double startX = 0;
        while (startX < size.width) {
          canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, 0), Offset(startX + dashWidth, 0), paint);
          startX += dashWidth + dashSpace;
        }
    
        // Draw right border
        double startY = 0;
        while (startY < size.height) {
          canvas.drawLine(
            Offset(size.width, startY),
            Offset(size.width, startY + dashWidth),
            paint,
          );
          startY += dashWidth + dashSpace;
        }
    
        // Draw bottom border
        startX = 0;
        while (startX < size.width) {
          canvas.drawLine(
            Offset(startX, size.height),
            Offset(startX + dashWidth, size.height),
            paint,
          );
          startX += dashWidth + dashSpace;
        }
    
        // Draw left border
        startY = 0;
        while (startY < size.height) {
          canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, startY), Offset(0, startY + dashWidth), paint);
          startY += dashWidth + dashSpace;
        }
        
    
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's missing the override shouldRepaint

Answer (score -10):

BorderStyle.none can be useful if you wanna apply some animation or remove\add border function onTap(like a lighting border) event or similar.