# Flutter - How to get dashed InputDecoration border in TextFormField?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Expected design: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukIeU.jpg)

This is how the current InputDecoration looks like. I want to give a dashed stroke circular border with adjustable gap values.

```
 InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15.0),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Kolors.accent, width: 5.0,),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
            ),)
```

Comment: Please add a picture of what you want to do.

Comment: Hey Farwa, please follow this answer, this will definitely help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55034574/5362583

Answer (score 0):

I've figured there's no dashed `InputBorder` feature as of now for `TextFormField`. However, I have found a solution for that using this package [dotted_border](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border#-readme-tab-).

Solution:

```
                  DottedBorder(
                      color: _isFocused ? Kolors.accent : Kolors.stroke,
                      strokeWidth: 1.5,
                      dashPattern: [7, 4],
                      borderType: BorderType.RRect,
                      radius: Radius.circular(40),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _promoController,
                        cursorColor: Kolors.textGrey,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Kolors.textBlack,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                            ),
                            hintText: "Type your promocode",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Kolors.textHint,
                                fontSize: 14)),
                      ),
                    ),
```